# Is it possible to transfer the normals of a mesh to Geometry node hair or Particle Hair?

Tags: materials

In my endless quest to try and create good stylized fur shaders in Blender, I wanted o try and experiment messing around with the normals of Hair to create stylized hair. But so far, it seems that I can't seem to access that information in Blender, or atleast nowhere near enough of what I need.

So, I want to know how to transfer the normals of the mesh of my character to it's fur. Can it be done?

So far, Blender hair seems to be only good for super photorealistic stuff, which is not really what I want. I want to have full control over the hair shading properties so I can create more stylized, or even painterly look to my fur, but seems you can't access that information?

Just to make sure, we're talking about Particle Hair or Geometry Nodes Hair, not mesh hair. People seem to associate stylized fur with meshes, that is not what I want. I want to stylize the way the hair is shaded in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer the normals from the base mesh you can do it this way, but it requires the hair mesh to be an instance of an actual object, not generated entirely within Geometry Nodes.

[image]

This is because, to my knowledge, there isn't yet a way to set an object to use auto smooth, via GN exclusively, which the DataTransfer modifier is reliant on to work.

Comment: And if I use particle hair instead? Would it be possible?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I imagine the capabilities would be similar, but likely less all-encompassing. AFAIK the dev team has deemphasized further development on the Particles system and is transitioning to make GN the default tool to use in it's place. So I haven't really used particles in awhile, since GN can do everything it can and more.